# C++ Can't change Element in Char Array

Tags: c++

I'm new to C coming from Java. Just explain me why this:

```html
text[0] = 'a';
```

is not possible, my program just crashes.

```css
#include "caesarHead.h"
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {

 caesar("Hello this is a sample text", 12);

 printf("\n\n");
}


void caesar(char text[], char offset) {
 int i = 0;
 text[0] = 'a';
 char *p = text;

 for (p; *p != '\0'; p++) { 
   
  printf("String: %c \n", text[i]);
  printf("Ascii: %i \n", (int)text[i]);
  i++;
 }
}
```

Comment: "I'm new to C" - spo why does your title and tag say "C++"??

Comment: Use C tag or std::string or if your compiler already supports it std::string_view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify *string literal*. In fact, you can try but this is *undefined behavior* and it may or may not work.

Instead, put your string to variable first and then use it. In this case, you string is initialized when `main` is called and it is put on *stack* therefore you are able to modify it later.

```
int main(void) {
    char str[] = "Hello this is a sample text";
    caesar(str, 12);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

*String literal* must be used as non-modifiable string. When trying to modify such a string, we have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I don't get it, I have a char Array. at Index 0 of that char array I try to set the element to 'a' and it doesn't work. Why ? And to what exactly are you trying to refer as String, isn't that a char array ?

Comment: Because you used *string literal* and not string from RAM. *String literal* may be put to section which can't be modified. @PssstZzz

Comment: @PssstZzz This is a non-modifiable char array. String literals are those.